# Scrapy Spider - How to take a start url and increment a page # to crawl ending with page value?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to crawl [this site](https://www.freepik.com/search?format=search&query=&sort=popular&type=vector&page=1) and on this page at the bottom there is a number 33,400 which you can get via response.css('span.pagination__pages::text').extract_first() I want to first convert that to just 33400 and then in the start_urls in my code I want to increment from page=1 to page=33400 and that value be pulled from the css span specified above. Currently my code below looks for the next page link and gets that href but I am having issues with it getting through all 33,400 pages it only gets about 100ish in and stops. I thought this maybe a better solution but I need help on how to write that within my code.

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "exampleurls"
allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
start_urls = ["https://www.example.com/search?format=search&page=1&query=&sort=popular&type=vector"]


def parse(self, response):
    # self.log('I just visited: ' + response.url)
    # for quote in response.css('div.showcase__content'):
    #    item = {
    #        'url': quote.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first(),
    #    }
    #    yield item

    urls = response.css('div.showcase__content > a::attr(href)').extract()
    for url in urls:
        url = response.urljoin(url)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_details)

    # follow pagination link
    next_page_url = response.xpath("//a[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' pagination__next ')]/@href").extract_first()
    if next_page_url:
        next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url, callback=self.parse)

def parse_details(self, response):
    yield {
        'name': response.css('h1.mg-none::text').extract_first(),
        'creation-date': response.xpath('//@data-creation-date').extract_first(),
        'downloads': response.xpath('//@data-downloads').extract_first(),
        'image-small': response.xpath('//@data-image-small').extract_first(),
        'main-keyword': response.xpath('//@data-main-keywords-label').extract_first(),
        'url': response.xpath("//meta[@property='og:url']/@content").extract(),
        'is-premium': response.xpath('//@data-premium').extract_first(),
        'is-selection': response.xpath('//@data-selection').extract_first(),
    }
```

Comment: Try to enable duplicates debugging and see what it writes there, maybe, cause it sorted by "popular" service rearranges somehow pages when crawler  on 100ish page or it just lies about 33k pages and there is only about 100ish and dupefilter bumps in that limit.

Comment: Also, try to sort by recent or generate all links for start urls (or in underlying function) at once, something like(where you getting this 30000 number at first start):
`all_urls = [f'https://www.freepik.com/search?format=search&page={str(x)}&sort=recent&type=vector' for x in range(1,30000)]`

Comment: What error message do you get when it stops? It could possibly be that the website is starting to block you, or you are overloading the server. If that is the reason, then your number method might also fail.

Answer (score 2):

world!

So, you want to range through a set of numbers, add them to the request and so forth well it should pretty easy.

1. A quick hacky way to achieve this would be to include a range in the "star_urls" so to traverse through ...

```
start_urls = ["https://www.example.com/search?format=search&page=%s&query=&sort=popular&type=vector"% page for page in xrange(33400)]
```

The best solution, in this case, would be to use a Crawl Spider with link extractor rule sets.